# How can I reset some data in a Firestore database in my SwiftUI app after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I have some SwiftUI app where when the user does something it creates a document for them with some fields and stuff. But now I want this document to reset all the fields(they're all ints) to 0 after some time(for example 24 hours) does anyone know how I would go about doing this? So user sends input -> creates document for them -> document gets updated with some data during this time -> after 24 hours document fields get reset. How would I do something like this?

Comment: We cannot guarantee the user will have the app open or your app will have the chance to reset the data on an external store. Instead I recommend setting up a Cloud Function on Firebase to monitor data changes, and set a task for resetting the data after 24 hours have passed. The trigger for this data wipe will need some tweaking.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @mani! 

Comment: Yeah thank you @mani that was what I was planning and I'm starting to look into Firebase Cloud Functions(know basically nothing about them) I'm about to upgrade to the Blaze tier on Firebase but there shouldn't be a problem with resetting the data every 24 hours to some data grabbed from some API right? Like I just wanna make sure it's capable of that(it probably is) but like just make it so if I get some document, it resets every field after 24 hours and the new field values are just values grabbed from some API I have, that's possible right?

Comment: Yes, its possible. Firebase Cloud functions can access the Firestore and modify any data. You'll probably want to store some sort of last modified date, and write the function to wipe after time has passed. It can be triggered every n mins or triggered on every date update/write (but that is one of the design decisions up to you).